# How to use BigQueryOperator with execution_date?

Tags: airflow

This is my code:

```
EXEC_TIMESTAMP  = "{{  execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')  }}"
query = """
        select ... where date_purchased between TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(cast ( {{ params.run_timestamp }} as TIMESTAMP), HOUR, 'UTC') ...
        """
generate_op = BigQueryOperator(
                    bql=query,
                    destination_dataset_table=table_name,
                    task_id='generate',
                    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
                    use_legacy_sql=False,
                    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                    query_params={'run_timestamp': EXEC_TIMESTAMP},
                    dag=dag)
```

This should work but it doesn't.
The render tab shows me:

```
between TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(cast (  as TIMESTAMP), HOUR, 'UTC')
```

The date is missing. It's being rendered into nothing.

How can I fix this? There is no `provide_context=True` for this operator. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luis, the `query_params` are not the `params` you can refer to in the templating context. They are not added to it. And since `params` is empty, your `{{ params.run_timestamp }}` is either `""` or `None`. If you changed that to `params={'run_timestamp':…}` it would still have a problem because `params` values are not templated. So when you use a templated field `bql` to include `{{ params.run_timestamp }}` you will get exactly what's in `params: {'run_timestamp': …str… }` filled in WITHOUT any recursive expansion of that value. You should get `{{  execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')  }}`.

Let me try re-writing this for you (but I may have got the parens around cast incorrectly, not sure):

```
generate_op = BigQueryOperator(
                    sql="""
select ...
where date_purchased between
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(cast('{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}}') as TIMESTAMP), HOUR, 'UTC')
...
                    """,
                    destination_dataset_table=table_name,
                    task_id='generate',
                    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
                    use_legacy_sql=False,
                    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                    dag=dag,
)
```

You can [see the `bql` and `sql` fields are templated](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L96). However the [`bql` field is deprecated and removed](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L102) in later code.

Comment: I tried this as well it does not render. It uses it as string. This operator doesn't have provide_context=True

Comment: Elsewhere you mentioned you were using v1.9 in which you must use `bql` not `sql` But yeah…https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/models.py#L1751 defines the templating context and it's basically the same for all tasks in a dag run and should always include an `execution_date` so I'm surprised to hear that it didn't expand that template for you when used directly.

Comment: Well it does render because I see it in the Render page  but there is no value ( pasted the example in the question ). This could be a bug.

Comment: @Luis definitely if you're getting a `None` for an `execution_date` which is the basis of defining a dag_run and task_instance, there's some kind of bug happening there. And this is limited to the BigQueryOperator? It seemed you were reporting some success with a PythonOperator (as a work around).

Comment: There is defiantly a bug. I worked around by adding PythonOperator to render the SQL - saving it to a file and then the BigQueryOperator reads the SQL from the file without need to render it.  I really hope that they will fix this. BigQueryOpeartor is widely used,

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are using `query_params` which is not a templated field as @dlamblin mentioned.

Use the following code that directly uses the `execution_date` date inside `bql`:

```py
import airflow
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
import os


CONNECTION_ID = Variable.get("Your_Connection")

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 12, 27, 11, 15),
    'retries': 4,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10)
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='My_Test_DAG',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='15 * * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
)

query = """select customers_email_address as email, 
   from mytable
   where 
    and date_purchased = TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(cast ({{  execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')  }} as TIMESTAMP), HOUR, 'UTC'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) """

create_orders_temp_table_op = BigQueryOperator(
                    bql = query,
                    destination_dataset_table='some table',
                    task_id='create_orders_temp_table',
                    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
                    use_legacy_sql=False,
                    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                    dag=dag)

start_task_op = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)


start_task_op  >> create_orders_temp_table_op
```